# How can I use HTML5 download attr in iPhone using PhoneGap

Tags: ios, iphone, html, cordova, download

I have a PhoneGap application that is working on Android. The app accesses mp3 audios from a server and plays for the user. It also uses HTML5 download feature to download any audio.

I am now compiling this for iPhone and I have been told that one cannot download stuff like MP3 audios on iPhone hence this HTML5 download won't work.

I am seeking confirmation if and how the download facility works on iPhone? I am totally new to iPhone.

Comment: iOS has a closed filesystem, meaning that the user has not access to it. Thus you can not download files of the web. With in Cordova you can access your apps document directory and save files there. But the user will not be able to access then and your app is the only one who can access the files.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes. Then how can my application access those downloaded files? Any examples?

Comment: Start by reading the Cordova documentation: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

Comment: Thank you @rckoenes. Will dig out :-)